# String Extraction from file

Tags: bash, grep

I have  a file with the following lines:

```
Aug 25 11:20:19   master set to 'John Jacob' (ID 12345) based on [Created Date] = '2014-05-30 20:58:59'
Aug 25 11:20:19  some text
Aug 25 11:20:49   master set to 'Jane Joy' (ID 6789) based on [Created Date] = '2014-05-30 20:59:07'
Aug 25 11:20:19 more text
Aug 25 11:20:19  more text ("ID not found")
Aug 25 11:20:19  master is even more text ("ID Not found") but alternate ID (ID 11358) exists"
```

I'm trying to extract the string beginning with "master" until the ")" of the (ID 12345).

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
grep "master set to" | cut -d ")" -f input.txt
```

However when I run this, everything in the text file returns. Is my usage of grep and cut in correct?

Thanks in advance,
simak

Comment: When I run your attempt, I get an error because `-f` expects an argument. Which `cut` are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use GNU Grep's `--only-matching` Flag

```
$ grep --only-matching 'master.*)' input.txt 
master set to 'John Jacob' (ID 12345)
master set to 'Jane Joy' (ID 6789)
master is even more text ("ID Not found") but alternate ID (ID 11358)
```

Comment: Third line stops with last `)` and not first.  Not sure if this is what OP wants. If so, then you could change `grep` to: `grep -o 'master[^)]*)'`

Answer (score 0):

your line should really be

```
grep "master set to" input.txt | cut -d ")" -f 1
```

Note however that it will strip the trailing `)` and will keep the date at the beginning.

```
$ grep "master set to" input.txt | cut -d")" -f1
Aug 25 11:20:19   master set to 'John Jacob' (ID 12345
Aug 25 11:20:49   master set to 'Jane Joy' (ID 6789
```

See @Codegnome's answer for a better approach still using `grep`

Answer (score 0):

You can try regular expressions with `grep`

`grep 'master.+\)' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt`

Comment: This will get the whole line, not just the part between `master set to` and the closing paren.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` may do:

```
awk -F"master " 'NF>1 {split($2,a,")");print a[1]")"}' file
set to 'John Jacob' (ID 12345)
set to 'Jane Joy' (ID 6789)
is even more text ("ID Not found")
```